Why Scala function returns Map[List[Nothing], myObj]
When I call this function, I got Map[List[Nothing], myObj] instead of Map[List[Any], myObj]
In the code below, the function converts a sequence of objects into a map, where the keys are constructed from the specified fields and the values are the objects themselves.
The function returns a A map where the keys are lists of specified fields and the values are the corresponding objects from the sequence.
  def seq2map[T <: Product](seq: Seq[T], keyFields: List[String]): Map[List[K], T] = {
    seq.map { obj =>
      val key = keyFields
        .map { fieldName =>
          val method = obj.getClass.getMethod(fieldName)
          method.invoke(obj).asInstanceOf[AnyRef]
        }
        .asInstanceOf[List[K]]
      key -> obj
    }.toMap
  }

// My class
case class myObj(
    eco_designed: Option[Boolean],
    model_code: Option[String],
    update_date: Option[Timestamp],
    update_user: Option[String],
    valid_from: Option[Timestamp],
    valid_to: Option[Timestamp])

// My sequence I want to transform to map with a list of values as key
// Example of key: List["123456", "2024-05-15 16:58:08.675", "2024-05-15 16:58:08.675"]
val objs: Seq[myObj] = Seq(
  myObj(Some(true), Some("A"), Some(new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis())), Some("User1"), Some(new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis())), Some(new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis() + 10000))),
  myObj(Some(false), Some("B"), Some(new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis())), Some("User2"), Some(new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis())), Some(new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis() + 10000))),
  myObj(Some(true), Some("C"), Some(new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis())), Some("User3"), Some(new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis())), Some(new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis() + 10000)))
)

// Liste des champs à utiliser comme clés
val keyFields = List("model_code", "valid_from", "valid_to")

// Utilisation de la fonction seqToMap
val map = seqToMap(objs, keyFields)

As a result I've got a Map[List[Nothing], myObj], why?

Well, you are explicitly telling the compiler to return that type. Both in the function signature as well as with the asInstanceOf

What is the meta-problem you are trying to solve with that function?

Unrelated but don't use Timestamp class! It's 2024. Use java.time.Instant.

What is K you have not defined that type anywhere.

@GaëlJ To map a field of type Timestamp in a Delta Lake table using Scala, it is recommended to use the java.sql.Timestamp class. The main reason is that the Spark APIs, as well as file formats like Delta Lake, have historically used java.sql.Timestamp to represent timestamp data types. I know it's 2024 thank you for this "useful" information.
